# How can I enumerate shared folder sessions on a remote computer without WMI (preferably in C#)

Tags: windows

First allow me to start off with a short explanation of why I must do this with out WMI.

I am trying to list all the sessions attached to an EMC Celerra NS20.  This particular device allows you to connected to it with the Computer Management MMC snap-in to view shares, but I quickly found out that it is *NOT* MS Windows based and does not support WMI.

The reason I want to do this without using the snap-in is simply because I am trying to create a tool to monitor sessions across a set of servers (most of which are Windows Servers) to track what users are logged in, from where, and how many computers, etc.

I have searched and read extensively about the Celerra exposing and XML API (I thought this might be what the Computer Management Console used).  However, after running a packet capture to see what Compmgmt.msc was actually sending back and forth, it appears to be using SMB2 protocol.

So I am trying to figure out if there is:
A) A good library for doing this kind of work with SMB/Samba (preferably for C#).
B) If anyone knows a better way to retrieve this information.

If anyone has a good idea of how to do this but just not in C#, I am willing to implement this in any language and then pipe it into my program if necessary.

I hope I have clearly explained my problem.  Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.  Thank you for you time.

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for [NetSessionEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Luke, thank you for the quick reply.  In the process of trying to resolve this I ran across NetSessionEnum.  However it is my understanding that this returns information on inbound connections only.  That would require that the command is run on the CIFS server and in this case that is not possible.  I actually tried to use this in code as I found a C# wrapper for it. After some more research on PInvoke.net, I could only successfully retrieve information on my local machine, not the remote server (I believe I would receive Error 53 when I attempted).

Comment: A huge thank you to @Luke. My understanding was flawed but after searching long and hard for what Error 53 meant.  It turned out to be a result of how that the initial string passed in as the server name must be provided as LPCWSTR. 

I was finally able to enumerate all the sessions. I just needed to make sure I marshalled the input using the following line of code in the wrapper.

`code`[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string serverName `code`